# Gummer-psn php help need in installing

Tags: javascript, php, api

hello guys iam new to to psn api little bit confused on installing how can i do it simply i have test his test site but it given error below when i traid to get valid account but not resonding on non valid account  i have host knowledge of php and stuff here is below error gumer psn api given me on his test site i have not yet uploaded the script i wann know how to do it

```
An error occurred while processing your request.
```

Reference #30.379b1bc3.1480681309.aaeb303

please any can guide how can i do it need that badly wanna make some checker stuff if some dont know of gummer psn api here is link below

https://github.com/jhewt/gumer-psn

Answer (score 0):

You must have

- A valid PSN account (can be new)
- [Node.js / io.js](http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs)

This is not a PHP library.

> [In a nutshell, Node.js is a platform for server side activities. It uses the Javascript programming language and has a plethora of libraries available as npm modules. You can think of these npm modules as library dependencies that may be satisfied with Composer if you are coming from PHP land](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-php-get-started/) **https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-php-get-started/**
>
> [Integrating Node.js with PHP](https://entwickler.de/webandphp/integrating-node-js-with-php-125830.html) **https://entwickler.de/webandphp/integrating-node-js-with-php-125830.html**

Comment: ya it is js or nod.js liberary i have its implementation in php but dont know how to upload and work it properly

Comment: > Node.js is very easy to install. If you're using Windows or Mac, installers are available on the [download page](http://nodejs.org/download).